# Informix "Unable to load translation shared library (DLL). SQLCODE=-11048" problem

Tags: iis, django-rest-framework, informix, windows-server-2008-r2

As the title says, I’ve been trying to connect my application (django rest framework backend deployed on IIS 8 (windows server 12 R2) to Informix but it shows me the same error:

`[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Unable to load translation shared library (DLL). SQLCODE=-11048`

What is worth noting is:

- There are two versions of Informix installed on the server, and have been there for a long time, but this problem only started occurring recently.
- The only things that have been installed during the period where it stopped working are HTTP Platform Handler 1.2 and Application Request Routing 3.0.
- Proxy is enabled on the server in IIS.
- The connection string is configured correctly.

`SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=db_name;HOST=ip_address;SERVICE=port;Protocol=used_protocol;UID=user_name;PWD=password;`

What I tried :

- Tried disabling proxy to see if it was the problem, but nothing happened.
- Tried uninstalling HTTP Platform Handler, but it somehow refuses so nothing to note on that end.
- INFORMIXDIR is set correctly on both env and the setnet32 configs.
- Tested using the ConnectTestDemo, and one of the installed versions of the sdk works while the other gives me the same error.

I would appreciate any lead on how to solve this, however small. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that PATH (system one) has the Informix bin directory (%INFORMIXDIR%\bin)
The Informix ODBC driver (iclit09b.dll) needs some extra libraries which are located in that directory. Also, it may be a good idea to set INFORMIXDIR as an environment variable (system) rather than just using the registry (setnet32)

Comment: @jsagrera I already have the correct env variables (INFORMIXDIR and PATH) + setnet32. The thing is that it used to work perfectly fine and just stopped working recently. The configs were not changed. Thanks tho.

Comment: Since it has been working fine before, I think the configuration should be fine. Do you remember if you changed some configuration or other operations before the problem appeared? There are too few cases where this error can be referenced. You can see what's going on by generating logs with FRT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing.

Comment: The error "Unable to load translation shared library" means the ODBC driver failed to load some of the dependencies libraries. ODBC will attempt to load the ESQL/C libraries and those the GLS library. If any of those fails to load or their dependencies (C runtime) you will get that error.
The fact that you can see the error text means INFORMIXDIR is properly set, but PATH may not. If both variables are set as System variables (not just for the current user), then I suggest to get a trace with ProcessMonitor, it should show which DLL is failing to load.

Comment: @TengFeiXie Thank you for your answer. I haven't changed any configurations, but a couple of things have been installed (HTTP Platform handler and Application Request Routing), that's about all that I know of. As for using FRT, it unfortunately doen't seem to be an option in the server I'm working on and I don't have the authoritiy to make that sort of change on the server.

Comment: @jsagrera thank you for your answer, but as I am not allowed to make any kind of changes on the server, I'm not sure I'll be able to use ProcessMonitor.

Comment: Ok, the usual way is to Verify that the values for the INFORMIXDIR environment variable and PATH are correct. Your configuration should be correct. But tested with ConnectTestDemo, one version works and one gets the same error. This could be either path issue or permissions issue. Since you can't use tools for troubleshooting, it can only be suggested that you try to set INFORMIXDIR and PATH again, and check the name and path of the dll. The main thing is to find the translation DLL and check why it cannot be loaded. Exclude step by step according to the verification content mentioned.